# How to close datepicker ui calendar on click of "Today" button (Select current date + close calendar window)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

[Click this link to see image for reference. Today button should select current date and close calendar window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDiHF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    showButtonPanel: true,
    buttonImage: buttonCalendar,
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: ""
});
```

and call this js code in the pages where you have the calendar.

```
$.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) { 
    $(id).datepicker('setDate', new Date()).datepicker('hide').blur(); 
};
```